# Remap Caps Lock to Ctrl in Windows 10 without administrator privileges?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, keyboard-layout, capslock

I found this question:

- [Map capslock to control in windows 10](https://superuser.com/q/949385/504387)

Which would likely work great if I had admin rights on my machine.  But I don't.

I also found [a couple of](https://darrengoossens.wordpress.com/2017/06/27/caps-lock-disable-on-windows-without-admin-rights/) [links](https://dropline.net/2009/05/mapping-caps-lock-to-control-without-admin-access/) about remapping keys without admin rights *in Windows 7.*  The suggested solution is to use the following:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,1d,00,3a,00,00,00,00,00
```

(Save in a file with `.reg` extension, double-click to apply to the registry, and then reboot.)

This is the same as the first linked solution except for the key to edit; the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` key can be edited without admin rights.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work on Windows 10.  (It applies and creates the key, but even after reboot the Caps Lock key is caps lock, not ctrl.)

In `regedit` I see that under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Keyboard Layout` there are subfolders (subgroups?) for "Preload", "Substitutes", and "Toggle".  It seems likely to me that putting something in "Substitutes" might be the way to do this for Windows 10 but I've no idea what to put, and there is no documentation I can find.

How can I remap Caps Lock to Ctrl in Windows 10 without admin rights?

Comment: I'm a little surprised that anyone still wants to do that this many years after the Ctrl key was moved, but...  Would using AutoHotKey be an option for you?

Comment: I know how if you can access Local Machine, can you?

Comment: @Cris, I'm not sure how to tell.  If you post your answer I can try it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Map capslock to control in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/949385/map-capslock-to-control-in-windows-10)

Comment: @user202729 sorry but no, it doesn't.  Please read the first couple sentences of my post, where I already linked to that same question you just linked.

Comment: Some new answers posted there doesn't require admin privilege, so it's alright. Consolidate all the information in one place to make search easier. (that message is just autogenerated with flag as duplicate) (that having said, the AutoHotKey answer there was posted in 2018 which is one year earlier than your question)

Answer (score 10):

You can do that by using the free
[AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).
Since you cannot install software, you may get the portable version from
[AutoHotKey Downloads](https://autohotkey.com/download/).

Download `AutoHotkey.zip`, unzip it and use as follows.

This `.ahk` file will do the remapping:

```
Capslock::Ctrl
```

You may set AutoHotKey as the handler for `.ahk` files by running a modified
version of these commands for the right folder
(if you can):

```
assoc .ahk=AutoHotkeyScript
ftype AutoHotkeyScript="C:\path\to\AutoHotkey.exe" "%1"
```

If you cannot run the above, just start:

```
"C:\path\to\AutoHotkey.exe" "myscript.ahk"
```

You may also put a batch file that does the above (or similar) in your
Startup folder.

Comment: Works nice. But has no autostart feature and can not be minimized to system tray

Comment: @JuergenSchulze: AHK normally only works in the traybar, and the `.ahk` file can be put in the user's  Startup group that is found at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a small program called **Uncap** that was made exactly for this task (althought it can also be used to remap other keys).

How to make it work:

1. **Download the executable ([`uncap.exe`](https://github.com/susam/uncap/releases/download/0.3.0/uncap.exe))** from its [GitHub Releases page](https://github.com/susam/uncap/releases).
2. **Save the executable file to a permanent location.** For example:

   - Open a Windows Explorer window (**Windows logo key** <kbd>⊞</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>).
   - Click in the address bar, type `%USERPROFILE%`, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This opens your user profile folder.
   - Create a new folder named `Programs` there.
   - Move the `uncap.exe` executable file you downloaded to this folder.
3. **Create a shortcut inside your user's `Startup` folder** to make Uncap initialize at login:

   - Open a Windows Explorer window (**Windows logo key** <kbd>⊞</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>).
   - Click in the address bar, type `shell:startup`, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This opens your automatic initialization folder (`Startup`).
   - Righ-click inside the window, then select `New > Shortcut` in the menu.
   - In the dialog, find the executable or just paste this text as the location if you followed the example above:

     ```
     "%USERPROFILE%\Programs\uncap.exe" 0x14:0xa2
     ```
   - Make sure to include the '`0x14:0xa2`' bit after the executable path (separated by a space). It instructs Uncap to map <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to <kbd>Right Control</kbd> instead of mapping it to <kbd>Escape</kbd> by default.
   - Finish creating the shortcut. The next time you log in, Uncap will run automatically and remap <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>.
   - To make the mapping work immediately, double-click the shortcut. A small window will briefly open and close.