# Swap keys in keyboard without admin rights on Windows?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout

Is there any easy, preferable GUI, way to swap or manually define keys on the keyboard, on Windows 10, without admin rights?

All the tools I see around demand admin rights. But why, if the user should have the freedom to define his own keyboard settings?

Comment: Why don't you have admin rights?

Comment: @Moab because it's not my computer, I am just a user in a big org with a very specific keyboard

Comment: "But why, if the user should have the freedom to define his own keyboard settings?" Because you are an employee of a company, which controls everything on your pc.

Comment: @Moab but I can change my keyboard layout in Windows setting

Comment: Related question [Remap Caps Lock to Ctrl in Windows 10 without administrator privileges? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1473001/remap-caps-lock-to-ctrl-in-windows-10-without-administrator-privileges) (`uncap` should probably satisfy the requirement as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All the tools I see around demand admin rights. But why?

At a guess, probably because the software is being installed (an activity often limited to administrators).

On the other hand, certain software like [AutoHotkey has a zipped version](https://www.autohotkey.com/download/) which includes standalone executables that shouldn't require installation or administrative privileges (as far as I am aware). Of course, AutoHotkey isn't really a GUI program per se, as it runs text files you create, but it is generally fairly simple to do basic key swapping with.

Answer (score 1):

An old question but not fully answered.

While AutoHotKey is a great solution (that i use myself on PC without admin rights) it's not user friendly. For GUI experience you can choose PowerToys. It's MS build app with Keyboard Manager.

You just need to use that powershell script to install as local User https://gist.github.com/laurinneff/b020737779072763628bc30814e67c1a