# How to undo keybinds powershell

Tags: windows-10, powershell

> $hexified =
>   "00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,1d,00,3a,00,00,00,00,00".Split(',')
>   | % { "0x$_"};
>
> $kbLayout = 'HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout';
>
> New-ItemProperty -Path $kbLayout -Name "Scancode Map" -PropertyType
>   Binary -Value ([byte[]]$hexified);

I used these commands from here trying to swap capslock|esc and now not only does it not work, but my capslock is doing weird things. How can I undo these commands?

[Map capslock to control in windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/949385/map-capslock-to-control-in-windows-10?newreg=7b9d4eef1dc64568b31182e0dc78e323)

Comment: Did you back up your registry keys before making the change?

Comment: You must reboot your pc after changes.

Answer (score 0):

From the ***Admin* PowerShell** console:

```
$Key = 'HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout'
Remove-ItemProperty $Key 'Scancode Map'
```

Then restart.