# I mapped Caps Lock to Ctrl with PowerShell, how do I map it back?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, button-remapping

I'm using Window 10, I saw this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/949385/map-capslock-to-control-in-windows-10) and driven by curiousity I mapped Capslock to Ctrl in PowerShell with this code:

```
$hexified = "00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,1d,00,3a,00,00,00,00,00".Split(',') | % { "0x$_"};

$kbLayout = 'HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout';

New-ItemProperty -Path $kbLayout -Name "Scancode Map" -PropertyType Binary -Value ([byte[]]$hexified);
```

Can someone please kindly point out how do I map it back?

Comment: You could refer to this answer https://superuser.com/a/1554452/603073 or restore the registry backup you took before you executed the change... You could also just delete the scancode map from `HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout`

Comment: No such directory...

Comment: It won't be a directory, it'll be a key in the `HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout` set

Comment: Work like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone wishing to undo a scancode mapping of keys and return all keys to their
normal use:

- Run `regedit` (administrator permission required)
- Position to the key
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout`
- Right-click the value named "Scancode Map" and select "Delete".