# Map Caps Lock to Control in Windows 11

Tags: keyboard, windows-registry, windows-11, powertoys

See also [Map capslock to control in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/q/949385/92954).

In Windows 7 and 10, I was able to remap the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to act as a <kbd>Control</kbd> key by updating the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout\Scancode Map` key in the registry. I've documented the details [here](https://github.com/Keith-S-Thompson/no-caps-lock).

When I upgraded my personal laptop from Windows 10 to Windows 11, it continued to work as intended, but I later noticed that that key does not exist in the registry. I don't know how the system still knows to map <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to <kbd>Control</kbd>, but as far as that laptop is concerned, it's working the way I want it to.

I now have a work-issued laptop with Windows 11. Since the `...\Scancode Map` key doesn't exist in the registry, I can't change it. I've used the PowerToys Keyboard Manager to map <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to <kbd>Control</kbd>, but the mapping doesn't apply in all contexts. In particular, it doesn't apply on the login screen or in applications being run as Administrator. (The registry hack does.)

(I've mapped <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> so I can turn caps-lock off if it has been set accidentally.)

Is there a way to map <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to <kbd>Control</kbd> in Windows 11 that will apply in all contexts, including the login screen? Perhaps there's a Windows 11 registry key that corresponds to the Windows 10 `...\Scancode Map` key?

Comment: "doesn't apply in all contexts" - What exactly does this mean?

Comment: @Ramhound: He means in non-logged-in contexts.

Comment: I believe that `Scancode Map` still exists in Windows 11. Try returning it.

Comment: @harrymc I don't see it when I run the Registry Editor. What exactly do you mean by "Try returning it"?

Comment: Just create the registry item with the exact same value as you used in Windows 10.

Comment: @harrymc OK, I'll try that later. I'm still wondering about the fact that my personal laptop (W11 upgraded from W10) doesn't have that key, but still behaves as if it did.

Comment: I can confirm this hack does not work anymore in Win 11. Adding the entry does not change keyboard mapping anymore. It makes sense as you are upgrading from 10 to 11 and maybe the installation process is clever enough to copy the map to somewhere else and working. On a fresh installation I add the entry but not working. @harrymc if you find out which config is controlling the behaviour now in Win 11 please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: I just tested the registry trick in Windows 11 after reboot, and it half-works: CapsLock works like Ctrl, but Ctrl keeps its functionality. AutoHotKey does it perfectly well, but it requires login. At this point I don't think that there is a solution that works in non-login contexts.

Comment: Strange that it works for you, but only halfly. Now you have 2 control keys. I am still looking for where does it go.

Comment: @harrymc I haven't had a chance to try this yet. I actually prefer having both keys act as Control, so if I can't swap them that's not a problem for me.

Comment: OMG I found out why....  it's so weird that Win 11 suddenly starts to use `0xe0` as higher byte for scan codes; it also explains why you now have 2 control keys. Please check my answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/1827375/windows-11-scancode-map-registry-trick-does-not-work-anymore

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if the correct scancode also depends on the hardware/keyboard being used? I'm just setting up a new laptop with Windows 11 and I first tried `1d e0 3a e0` to remap caps -> control based on this answer, but after rebooting caps was still caps. Then I tried the traditional `1d 00 3a 00` and after rebooting caps is now control (as it should be).

Answer (score 0):

Change your higher bytes from `00` to `e0` and the registry trick will start to work.

So in your solution, instead of having:

```
0x001D003A
0x003A001D
```

try to put:

```
0xe01De03A
0xe03Ae01D
```

Seems Win 11 suddenly starts to use `0xe0` as first byte of scan codes wherever there will not cause confusion. See my question and answer [Windows 11 - scancode map registry trick does not work anymore](https://superuser.com/questions/1827375/windows-11-scancode-map-registry-trick-does-not-work-anymore)

Comment: I just tried that on my work-issued Windows 11 laptop, and it didn't work. I disabled the PowerToys keyboard manager, updated the registry, and rebooted, and the caps lock key still acts as caps lock. The value of the `Scancode Map` key is `00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 1d e0 3a e0 00 00 00 00`

Comment: Does you control work as CapsLock now? Want to figure out the order of old/new scan code

Comment: I adapted my "nocapslock" registry update for Windows 10. I don't want Control to work as CapsLock. I want both to act as Control. (Of course others might prefer to swap them.)