# How can I revert Caps Lock key mapping in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, remapping, key-binding, capslock

I have applied following answer Map <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> in Windows 10 (https://superuser.com/a/997448/723632). Now if possible, I want to revert it:

> In case anyone needed this done via `PowerShell`:

```
$hexified = "00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,1d,00,3a,00,00,00,00,00".Split(',') | % { "0x$_"};
$kbLayout = 'HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout';    
New-ItemProperty -Path $kbLayout -Name "Scancode Map" -PropertyType Binary -Value ([byte[]]$hexified);
```

> Run it as Administrator and reboot.

How can I revert this operation where I want to use <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> as its default mapping?

Comment: For key remapping on windows in general I suggest [SharpKeys](https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys/releases)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do this :

- Use `regedit` and position to the key
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout`.
- Right-click the item `Scancode Map` and select Delete
- Reboot.